# jQuery GetList Randomly

Tags: 2013, list, jquery

I have a GetList script already working as below.

```
jQuery( function($) {
var myfilter = "Show_x0020_item eq 'Yes'";
var pPrm = GetList("Cool Stuff","Title,Cool_x0020_Stuff_x0020_Type,Description,Link,Show_x0020_item&$orderby=Id desc","",myfilter,"",5);
```

But would like to change it, so it gets randomly 5 items with the same condition.
Has anyone done this before?

---

2017.11.26

Thank you! ThinkB4Code.
Here is the whole 'working' script.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
function GetRandomItems(listName){
    var sortOrder = ['asc', 'desc'];
    var sortProperty = ['Modified', 'Created', 'Author', 'Editor'];
    var sortIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    var sortPropIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    var skipCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250); // Replace 250 by the n number of items in list where Show Item column is Yes. You can get it from another REST Query.
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Cool Stuff')/Items?";
    url += "&$select=Title,Cool_x0020_Stuff_x0020_Type,Description,Link,Show_x0020_item";
    url += "&$filter=Show_x0020_item eq 'Yes'";
    url += "&$orderby="+ sortProperty[sortPropIndex] + " " + sortOrder[sortIndex]; // Sort randomly based on 4 propert available for both List and Lib.
    url += "&$skip=" + skipCount; // Skip the items on random base
    url += "&$top=5"; // GET Five Items only

$.ajax({
        url: url,
         method: "GET",
         headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data){

                    var shtml = '<ul class="cbs-List list-Links newColleagues-List">';
                    var count = 0;
                    $.each(data.d.results, function(i,result) {
                        var cType = '';

                        var linkURL = '';
                        result.Link == null ?  linkURL = "#" : linkURL = result.Link.Url

                        switch(result.Cool_x0020_Stuff_x0020_Type){
                            case 'Cultural learning initiatives':
                                cType = 'fa-balance-scale';
                                break;
                            case 'Word of the days':
                                cType = 'fa-comments';
                                break;
                            case 'Acronyms':
                                cType = 'fa-cogs';
                                break;
                            case 'Thought':
                                cType = 'fa-commenting';
                                break;
                            case 'Joke of the day':
                                cType = 'fa-smile-o';
                                break;
                            case 'Mind games':
                                cType = 'fa-puzzle-piece';
                                break;
                            default:
                                cType = 'fa-info';
                        }
                        shtml += '<li class="list-item-wrapper birthdayBoxMargin">'+
                                    '<span class="fa-stack fa-lg fa-2x icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon"></i><i class="fa '+cType+' fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span>'+
                                    '<div class="homeContentWrap ">'+
                                        '<div title="" class="ms-noWrap coolstuffTitle"><div title="" class="employeeBlurb2 coolstufText">'+result.Cool_x0020_Stuff_x0020_Type+ '<a class="coolLink" target="_blank" href="'+linkURL+'"></div>' +result.Title+'</a></div>'+
                                        '<div title="" class="employeeBlurb coolstufText">'+result.Description+'</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="clearboth"></div>'+
                                '</li>';
                        count++;
                    })
                    count == 0 ? shtml +='<li class="list-item-wrapper birthdayBoxMargin"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg fa-2x icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-3x icon"></i><i class="fa fa-info fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span><div class="homeContentWrap "><div title="" class="ms-noWrap birthdayTitle">No cool stuff here</div></div></li>':shtml += '</ul><!--<div><a class="rmore right " href="https://myvoice.ttaf.co.za/Lists/Cool%20Stuff/">View All</a></div>--> '
                    $('#CoolStuff').html(shtml);


        },
        error: function(error){    
            //alert("Error: "+  JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    })
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    GetRandomItems('Cool Stuff');
});
</script>
<div id="CoolStuff"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, you forgot to add `&` symbol before. It must be `&$filter` or `&$skip` etc.

Answer (score 1):

there is no direct way to get random data from SharePoint "JSOM/REST API" (I am not sure which one you are using).

But you can apply logic to get random data like following code sample using REST API.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    function GetRandomItems(listName){
        var sortOrder = ['asc', 'desc'];
        var sortProperty = ['Modified', 'Created', 'Author', 'Editor'];
        var sortIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        var sortPropIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        var skipCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250); // Replace 250 by the n number of items in list where Show Item column is Yes. You can get it from another REST Query.

        var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/Items?";
        url += "$filter=Show_x0020_item eq 'Yes'";
        url += "$orderby="+ sortProperty[sortPropIndex] + " " + sortOrder[sortIndex]; // Sort randomly based on 4 propert available for both List and Lib.
        url += "$skip=" + skipCount; // Skip the items on random base
        url += "$top=5"; // GET Five Items only

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(data){
                //Your code logic here.
            },
            error: function(error){

            }
        })
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        GetRandomItems('List Name Goes Here');
    });
</script>
```

In this, we are sorting randomly out of 4 columns available in each List and Lib. Apart from sorting, there is another logic which is skipping items on random basis (I am using a random number 250 here, but you can read the comment on code to understand more).